# C#. Как получить список источников (Sources) сайта по URL?

Tags: c#, html

не очень разбираюсь с обработкой html запросов через c# и прочего и столкнулся с проблемой, помогите, пожалуйста. Нужно получить список источников сайта. Изображение(1) в прикрепе. Как это сделать? При этом надо учитывать, что просто пропарсить html и получить их таким образом, я не могу, тк при входе появляется файл join, а нужный файл лежит в другом месте (Изображение 2 и 3).

[image: Список источников сайта который нужно получить]

[image: Join файл, который открывается при попытке парсинга страницы]

[image: Файл, который мне нужен]

Comment: *При этом в файле Join нет упоминания этого файла и ссылки на него

Comment: Какую конкретно задачу вы решаете? Ибо на сколько мне известно, это лишь фича браузера, которая в удобном виде показывает то, что он отловил и такого понятия, как "список источников" нету, есть запросы, которые ваш браузер отправляет и собственно все.